# XAMPP SQLSRV extensions not showing in phpinfo M1

Tags: php, pdo, xampp, apple-m1, sqlsrv

I was trying to run a php project that uses `sqlsrv` but after installing `XAMPP` and also tried `MAMP`, apparently `sqlsrv` and `pdo_sql` doesn't show in my `phpinfo()` no matter what i try. i downloaded the file and added the `nts.so` files to the extension dir and added it in php.ini and still not showing in the `phpinfo()`.

Comment: You also have to install the PHP drivers https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-the-sql-server-driver-for-php

Comment: I already downloaded the driver needed and added it to the extension folder, also added it to the php.ini but still not showing in phpinof

Comment: How about the ODBC Drivers https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I already installed it too, i followed this certain guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15 to install all needed drivers but i still cant make it show in phpinfo

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install the right version,
in my case,

php_pdo_sqlsrv_81_ts_x64 and
php_sqlsrv_81_ts_x64

after copying these two into xampp -> PHP -> ext folder

edit php.init file as this.

extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_81_ts_x64
extension=php_sqlsrv_81_ts_x64

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).